# Oracle SQL Select column aliases based on their conditional values

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I use a case statement to name columns based on the values they contain. I have members of a club who can sign up for Platinum, Gold, Silver and Bronze membership.  The data is stored in a table called CUST_MBR_INFO.  I want to be able to associate the customers by the membership type and CUST_ID. Is it possible to display the information as below in a combined single query? My queries work for getting the individual labels but I really want to use a single query. All the labels should be available with the CUST_IDs falling in the correct heading to be printed in a table.

PLATINUM_CUSTOMER     GOLD_CUSTOMER      SILVER_CUSTOMER        BRONZE_CUSTOMER

```
1222                   -            -                        -
-                     3122              -                        -
```

The membership type is based on the value of 2 columns

```
--CUST_ID 1222
--PLATINUM_CUSTOMER
SELECT CUST_ID,PROD_CODE AS PLATINUM_CUSTOMER FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'PLATINUM'
AND M_TYP_CDE = '1'



--CUST_ID 3122
--GOLD
SELECT CUST_ID,PROD_CODE AS GOLD_CUSTOMER FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'GOLD' 
AND M_TYP_CDE = '2'

--CUST_ID 3422
--SILVER
SELECT CUST_ID,PROD_CODE AS SILVER_CUSTOMER FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'SILVER'
AND M_TYP_CDE = '3'

--CUST_ID 94344
--BRONZE_CUSTOMER
SELECT CUST_ID,PROD_CODE AS BRONZE_CUSTOMER FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'BRONZE'
AND M_TYP_CDE = '4
```

Comment: You can't. Aliases must be hard-coded (unless you use dynamic SQL, which is very different from SQL - even though it has "SQL" in the name - and is strongly discouraged).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, one method is to use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT CUST_ID as Platinum, NULL as Gold, NULL as Silver, NULL as Bronze
FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'PLATINUM' AND M_TYP_CDE = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as Platinum, CUST_ID as Gold, NULL as Silver, NULL as Bronze
FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'GOLD' AND M_TYP_CDE = '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as Platinum, NULL as Gold, CUST_ID as Silver, NULL as Bronze
FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'SILVER' AND M_TYP_CDE = '3'
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as Platinum, NULL as Gold, NULL as Silver, CUST_ID as Bronze
FROM CUST_MBR_INFO
WHERE PROD_CATG_VAL = 'BRONZE' AND M_TYP_CDE = '4';
```

There are other methods to accomplish this, but this seems the simplest for your use-case.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was stuck on thinking about using a case statement. Grateful to you.